# jQuery / JavaScript: Changing URL hash from <input> tag or on form submit

Tags: javascript, hash, input

is it possible to somehow affect the hash of the URL from the `<input>` tag?

I need to initiate a search without a page refresh, but also want to change the URL hash, for example: `search.html#query=hello%20world`, when I have typed `hello world` in particular `<input>` and hit Enter (or submit).

UPD: I have an AJAX search, but I want to keep the history back and forward buttons working.

So, each time the user searches something, I want him to stay at the same page, load search results via AJAX and change the page's URL hash to enable the history buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
document.getElementById('search-form').onsubmit = function() {
    var hash = 'query=' + 
               encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('query').value);

    window.location.hash = hash;
};
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMhHF/).

Comment: With an AJAX search, be careful about `onsubmit` - depending on your HTML, the event may never fire.

Comment: Yes, I am currently using submit handler with a 'return false', will it still work?

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.hash` property to get and set the hash.

```
var e = document.getElementById('search');
window.location.hash = "#"+escape(e.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing this asynchronously, I can't tell you exactly how to do it, but I'll assume you have some sort of search function in which you get the value of the `input` and perform the search:

```
function your_search_function()
{
    var searchString = document.getElementById('your-input').val // get the value

    // do your search stuff...

    window.location.hash = 'query=' + encodeURIComponent(searchString);
}
```